# c++0x standard library reference manual

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, standards, manual

I've been coding in C++ for years and recently heard that there's a new revision of the C++ standard coming along. I've studied the standard drafts and found out that there's a lot of new stuff that will make my programming easier. So I want to get accustomed to the new standard before it comes out. However, it's pretty hard to code using the new standard library without having a decent reference manual around. I've googled and found only some pages like [Wikipedia's C++0x page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) which are **not** reference manuals. Does anybody know any C++0x standard library reference manual? I'm looking for something similar to MSDN's [Standard C++ Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscc687y.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There's been some good progress in getting the new features of C++0x on the [wiki-based cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com).  The documentation is primarily based on the [November 2010 draft standard (N3225)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf).

It's still far from complete, but it's getting better every day.

Answer (score 2):

Check your compiler's website/reference manual. Some compiler manufacturers have started adding the C++0x features, especially the ones already pre-finalized in the Technical Report 1. For example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx for the TR1 features Microsoft already included in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly older version of the C++0x draft can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscc687y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It's the same link you provided, but for VS2010 which implements some of the new standard. So far the only things I've found missing (not to say these are the only) are a for-each loop structure, and the C++0x multi-threading stuff.

I didn't look too much into this, but there's a list of features supported by GCC [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: How could you come up with the same link I've posted myself?

Comment: It's not exactly the same link, it's for VS2010 instead of for VS2005 which implements a good portion of the C++0x standard (again, it's an older version because VS2010 was released April of last year). VS2008 I think also might have some of the C++0x std libraries under std::tr1, but the core language is more or less C++03. I believe currently the most "up to date" compiler which uses C++0x is the GCC experimental compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be a reference manual for C++0x, because this standard is still experimental. C++0x is expected to be published by ISO around the end of 2011, so then there would be a reference manual (nutshell, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply try the features by using a recent compiler? Gcc implements a lot already (depending on the version) and Visual Studio 10 implements 5 new features.

I'm playing with lambda, auto and initializer lists at the moment at work and at home and it's really the kind of features that simplify everything you've write before.

Comment: The new standard is not always easy to interpret. If I simply try something out, and it doesn't work, I am often left wondering whether the problem is with my code or the compiler.